# Redirect user to different page if requirement is not met

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have roles setup for Admin and User. However the privileges for the roles are setup for editing purposes only. Admins can edit all content, users can only edit content belonging to them.

I have a Subscriptions table that shows which user is subscribe to the website based on the `cancelled` table. I have a conversations inbox, and I would like to restrict access to it. If user is found in the Subscriptions table with the `cancelled` column being `NULL` then that user is granted permission to view the conversations page. However if the user does not meet that requirement they should automatically be forwarded to our signup page to pay for a subscription.

Does someone know how I can implement this?

Conversations controller:

```
 def index
    @user = current_user
    sentbox_page = params[:page] if params[:sentbox].present?
    inbox_page = params[:page] if params[:inbox].present?
    mailbox = @user.mailbox
    @inbox = mailbox.inbox.paginate(:page => inbox_page, :per_page => 5)
    @sentbox = mailbox.sentbox.paginate(:page => sentbox_page, :per_page => 5)
    render layout: 'new_application'
  end

  def show
    user = current_user
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(user).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
    @conversation.receipts.recipient(user).update_all(is_read: true)
    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html {render layout: 'new_application'}
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_has_access

  # [...]

  protected
  def check_has_access
    if Subscription.exists?(user_id: current_user.try(:id) || -1, cancelled: nil)
      # has access
      return true
    else
      redirect_to signup_path
      return false
    end
  end
```

Short version of `check_has_access`:

```
def check_has_access
  redirect_to(signup_path) unless Subscription.exists?(user_id: current_user.try(:id) || -1, cancelled: nil)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that works as expected. Never used `protected` so good to know I can pickup this trick and use elsewhere. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

this would be a `before_filter`

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authorize, only: [:index, :show]
  ...
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def authorize
    sub = Subscription.where('user_id = ?', current_user.id).first
    return if sub && sub.cancelled == nil
    redirect_to :root, alert: "Please sign up to be able to do this"
  end
end
```

Comment: OP said `If user is found in the Subscriptions table with the cancelled column being NULL then that user is granted permission to view the conversations page`, your code does the opposite

Comment: @MrYoshiji ?? really?  if the user if found and sub.cancelled I return. Since there was no redirect, the before_filter should allow the controller action to continue, no?  I only fall through to `redirect_to` if I don't return in the previous line.

Comment: Oh, my bad, didn't pay as much attention as I should have... Sorry Steve!

Comment: @MrYoshiji no probs. :)